# How to calculate credit and debit from single column 'Amount'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four columns as follows:

| User_ID | Credit_Account | Debit_Account | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18595 | PKR1000100013010 | PKR1000023233010 | 1364500 |
| 16133 | PKR1616100013001 | 125450528 | 1826 |
| 16387 | PL52008 | 130984886 | 4560 |
| 18768 | PKR1007000010025 | PL64084 | 4000 |
| 18540 | 131014988 | 131013728 | 159092 |
| 18386 | 105090145 | PKR1000100013010 | 167079 |

How do I calculate `Total Credit Amount` and `Total Credit Amount`?

I tried the following which is a mess I think:

```
SELECT USER_ID , SUM(CR_total) as Total_Credit
FROM
(
        SELECT  USER_ID
             , Credit_Account
             , AMOUNT as CR_total
        FROM table  
        GROUP BY USER_ID
)CR

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT USER_ID , SUM(DR_total) as Total_Debit
FROM
(
        SELECT USER_ID
             , Debit_Account
             , AMOUNT as DR_total
        FROM table
        GROUP BY DR.USER_ID
)DR
ON DR.USER_ID = CR.USER_ID
group by USER_ID
ORDER BY USER_ID
```

**Expected Results:**

| User_ID | Credit_Account | Credit Amount against CA | Debit Amount against CA | Debit_Account | Credit Amount against DA | Debit Amount against DA | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18595 | PKR1000100013010 |  |  | PKR1000023233010 |  |  | 1364500 |
| 16133 | PKR1616100013001 |  |  | 125450528 |  |  | 1826 |

And since there might be duplication of accounts in both columns(`Credit_Account` and `Debit_Account`), the required debit/credit amounts can be aggregated against each account.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh Sorry for that. I have updated the question.

Comment: Your amended question shows expected results that appear to just be the original data plus several empty columns. It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY( VALUES...)` to reshape your data into Account, Credit_Amount, and Debit_Amount. Standard grouping and aggregation operations can then be performed.

```
SELECT
    C.Account,
    SUM(C.Credit_Amount) AS Total_Credit_Amount,
    SUM(C.Debit_Amount) AS Total_Debit_Amount
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        (D.Credit_Account, D.AMOUNT, 0),
        (D.Debit_Account, 0, D.AMOUNT)
) C(Account, Credit_Amount, Debit_Amount)
GROUP BY C.Account
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uMUyaYYf).

The zero amounts may also be replaced will NULLs if you prefer.

If accounts are user-specific, you can add D.User_ID to the group by and select list.

Comment: but I don't have credit/debit amounts separately

Comment: But if you click on the SQL fiddle link you'll see this working with your data in the format you posted it in